# Getting IExpress to install to copy files to right location

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, archive, iexpress

I'm trying to have an IExpress EXE that copies some files to a directory in "Program Files" but I'm struggling to get it to work. So far I have one File I want to copy, and the one .bat file in the EXE. I know that IExpress EXE's extract their contents to `%\temp%\IXP000.TMP` so I thought that I could easily copy the file to the Program Files folder by having the following in the .bat file:

```
mkdir C:\"Program Files"\HybRIDS
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy %temp%\IXP000.TMP C:\"Program Files"\HybRIDS /i
```

But when I run the EXE and take a look there's nothing in my Program Files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `%temp%` defined? Also, try putting quotes around the whole destination folder.

Comment: Ah this is embarrassing - apparently xcopy is not on this Windows box, or is not in any path anyway: `xcopy is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Perhaps I should use copy instead.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I've heard that xcopy has been deprecated for years in favor of Robocopy, but I'm not familiar with any version of Windows that doesn't still have it.

Comment: I'm wondering would %CD% work better instead of %temp%\IXP000.TMP?

Comment: Using %temp% shouldn't cause a problem. Are you getting any sort of error? xcopy will tell you whether or not any files were copied.

Comment: It all goes to fast an disappears before it's possible to see what happened. I thought it was admin privileges, but running the EXE as administrator does not help.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to refer the the temp folder directly; just assume the current working directory:

```
@echo off
rem install.bat
mkdir %ProgramFiles%\HybRIDS
echo %ERRORLEVEL% created directory %ProgramFiles%\HybRIDS
copy * C:\"Program Files"\HybRIDS
echo %ERRORLEVEL% copied files
del C:\"Program Files"\HybRIDS\install.bat
echo %ERRORLEVEL% success?
```

When you configure the sed for testing, make sure to maximize the installation `ShowInstallProgramWindow=3` and correctly set the installation script `AppLaunched=cmd /c install.bat`.  Also add the `pause` statement at the end of the batch script like [BambiLongGone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333551/bambilonggone) suggested for testing.  I used the follow format for error handling (assuming the installation window is hidden `ShowInstallProgramWindow=1`)

```
@echo off
REM install.bat    
mkdir %ProgramFiles%\HybRIDS 
REM mkdir may fail because the folder already exists - ignore errors.    

move * %ProgramFiles%\HybRIDS > temp.txt 2>&1
set i=%ERRORLEVEL%
REM check for errors!
if not %i%==0 (
    REM inform the user with a prompt (will not wait for it to close though...)
    start cmd /c^
        echo error occured during installation^
&       type temp.txt^
&       echo what to do next...^
&       pause
)
REM don't keep the install and temp.txt file
del %ProgramFiles%\install.bat
del %ProgramFiles%\temp.txt
```

If you have any questions just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that IExpress EXE's extract their contents to %\temp%\IXP000.TMP

Is not true. It extracts to a sub folder of temp.

```
mkdir "%ProgramFiles%\HybRIDS"
copy "%~dp0\IXP000.TMP" "%ProgramFiles%\HybRIDS"
```

Put a `pause` at end of batch file. It will remain in temp to check the sub folder (mine is 1), plus you'll see any error messages. Make sure `Echo` is Off.

Comment: Actually that *is* true – IExpress does extract to `%temp%\IXPnnn.TMP` (where _nnn_ is normally 000, but will increase by 1 until it finds a directory not in use).

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t a very complete answer (unlike owns’s). But most errors I’ve seen with IExpress and batch files are caused by people calling them directly, rather than via `cmd.exe`.

Make sure you’re running it like:

```
cmd /c mybatch.bat
```